# Add leading zeros with R to a SQL database

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, teradata, r-dbi

To add leading zeros to a string in R I'll use the `formatC()` function:

```
x <- c(1, 10, 100, 10000, 100000, 1000000)
formatC(x, width = 8, format = "d", flag = "0")
#> [1] "00000001" "00000010" "00000100" "00010000" "00100000" "01000000"
```

When I try and apply this to a Teradata SQL database I get the following error (guessing that `formatC` isn't supported):

```
tbl(db_name, "tbl_name") %>% 
  mutate(col5 = formatC(col4, width = 9, format = "d", flag = "0"))
#> Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
#>   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:7000: 60100: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]
#> [Teradata Database](-2275)Syntax error: Data Type "col5" does not match a
#>   Defined Type name. In addition: Warning message: 
#>   Named arguments ignored for SQL formatC
```

How can I add leading zeros to a Teradata SQL database when R is my front end?

Comment: in Teradata SQL there's `to_char(x, '09999999')` for numeric data and `LPAD(TRIM(x), 8, '0')` or strings.

Comment: @dnoeth works great! any interest in writing that up as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Teradata SQL there's no function named `formatC`, but you can get a similar reuslt using

```
to_char(x, '09999999') -- numeric x
LPAD(x, 8, '0')        -- varchar x
```